# Vector network analyzer and an Arduino

Tags: arduino, rf, antenna, communication, labview

Can you give an advice how to improve this? I want to combine a VNA with an Arduino in an RF anechoic chamber. The position contol will be performed by the Arduino.

[image: the project is that I want to do]

[Reference article](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8321830/figures#figures)

Comment: which part requires improvement?

Comment: @jsotola Thanks for answer. Especially, position controller for receiver.

Comment: you could outline the `Position Controller` box in contrasting color ... you cannot really improve a simple diagram ... it is already clear enough